# Unable to perform hive exchange partition due to failure of: Partition already exists

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to exchange a partition from staging db after merging the incremental data with the existing one as below:

1. Created staging table with partition:

   `CREATE TABLE stg.customers_testcontrol_staging(customer_id bigint,customer_name string, customer_number string,status string,attribute_category string,attribute1 string, attribute2 string, attribute3 string, attribute4 string, attribute5 string) PARTITIONED BY (source_name string) ROW FORMAT SERDE'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat' Location('/apps/hive/warehouse/stg.db/customers_testcontrol_staging'`
2. Inserted data into above table after merging with the base table data

   `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE finstg.customers_testcontrol_staging PARTITION (source_name) SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM base.customers where source_name='ORACLE' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM external.customers_incremental_data) t1 JOIN (SELECT customer_id,source_name, max(updated_date) max_modified FROM (SELECT * FROM base.customers where source_name='ORACLE' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM external.customers_incremental_data) t2 GROUP BY customer_id,source_name) s ON t1.customer_id=s.customer_id AND t1.source_name=s.source_name;`

Primary Keys of the table I am performing the join are: customer_id & source_name

3. Exchange partition step:

   `ALTER TABLE base.customers EXCHANGE PARTITION (source_name = 'ORACLE') WITH TABLE stg.customers_testcontrol_staging;`

But the exchange partition step fails with the exception:

> **Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10118]: Partition already exists [customers(source_name=ORACLE)]**

I took the syntax from [Hive Confluence page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Exchange+Partition)

Is there anything I missed to include in the EXCHANGE partition statement ? Could anyone let me what is the mistake I am doing here & how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run **`exchange partition`** successfully, Your destination table `base.customers`  cannot contain the partition that you are exchanging.

- But `base.customers` table is already have the **partition(source_name=ORACLE)** that you are exchanging.

**`Resolution:`**

- Delete the existing `partition` in destination table and run the exchange partition command again.

***(or)***

- Exchange the partition that is already not exists in destination
  table.
- If you want to just append the data to `Destination` table then run insert into `base.customers` table by selecting from
  `stg.customers_testcontrol_staging` table.

> [**`From HiveDocs: Constraints for Hive Exchange partitions:`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Exchange+Partition)
>
> 1. The destination table cannot contain the partition to be exchanged.
> 2. The operation fails in the presence of an index.
> 3. Exchange partition is not allowed with transactional tables either
>    as source or destination. Alternatively, use LOAD DATA or INSERT
>    OVERWRITE commands to move partitions across transactional tables.
> 4. This command requires both the source and destination table names to
>    have the same table schema.   If the schemas are different, the
>    following exception is thrown:
> 5. The tables have different schemas. Their partitions cannot be
>    exchanged